# When releasing an application, how to disable pages used during devolpment?

Tags: jsf, maven, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish

Is there a way to disable JSF pages when deploying to a production environment, but use these features in a development environment?

I am using Java EE with JSF to create a web application. I use a number of JSF pages to carry out debugging and testing. I want to disable these pages when the application is deployed in its production environment. No-one, not even develops will need to use these pages on the deployed application, so I want to disable them as a security precaution.

I do not want to simply restrict access to authenticated users. Firstly, this makes it tedious to use the debug features, as a login is required. And secondly, the debug features are quite powerful, and if there is a vulnerability in my web application, it could be devastating for an attacker to gain access to these features.

Comment: Do you use some packaging tool like maven? Then it should be quite straight forward to achieve

Comment: I do use maven, but I'm unsure of how to achieve this with Maven, yet. Let the research begin.

Comment: Easy with maven. Suposing you've not any link through the application accessing the JSF testing views, just use maven web resources option to omit all the testing stuff (I would do it for xhtml and beans) when you build the production war. You can differ between debug-production using maven profiles.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html).

Comment: At this stage, I would accept an answer if you wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Maven WAR plugin in order to exclude resources from your build. You are allowed to use wildcards an even expressions to specify what you want to exclude.

Let's refer to some adapted example from the docs:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>*-test.xhtml</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

That will exclude all the *-test.xhtml* ended resources from the root of your web application. You can develop this as far as you want to accomplish your requirements.

**See also:**

- [Including and Excluding Files From the WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html)